# Find the correct code: Clues A .. D, 13 to open the door

Tags: pattern

This is a puzzle of a game where I know the solution, but not how it is derived. So the correct answer goes to whoever can also explain the solution.

Find the correct code:

This is written on top of a closed door:

A..D

And this is a number on the closed door:
13

On the floor the following table can be found:

```
A | + | 2
--+---+---
- | 3 | -
--+---+---
8 | + | D
```

You have to find the correct 4 digit code.

Since nobody found the solution after a week, I'm now adding a part of the correct answer as hint. If this doesn't help, I'll add the complete solution in another week.

**Hint**

> The middle part of the code contains the 13: so A13D
>  A and D are replaced by single digits. But which?

Comment: Is the door locked? If it is closed, how can we read what is written on top of it?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK It's written above the door

Comment: You mean on the door-frame or on the wall above the door? Is it significant precisely where it is written?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK on the wall

Comment: It does not have any significance

Comment: Is this a sudoku puzzle?

Comment: or is this a magic square with the key being 13? if so then solving A and D would be the code?

Comment: Is there any significance to the fact that $2^3=8$?

Comment: I'm looking at the grid and I'm thinking that the + signs and minus signs are not math symbols but rather indications of vertical and horizontal lines like they are inbetween the grid squares. That indicates that the 3x3 grid has 3 rows, but there's a single column connection down the middle. That might help to narrow down the relationship.

Comment: This is driving me crazy.

Comment: I'm not aware of any significance of 2^3 = 8

Comment: Was the expression on the top of the door "A..D" as you have it, or something else like "ABCD" or "A13D", or "A[Door with '13']D"? Is the '13' on the door and the '13' in the two middle digits just a coincidence?

Comment: Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

So my theory is it works for reading across and up and down.

So two equations with 2 unknowns:

$A+2-3-8+D=13$ and  $A-8+3+2-D=13$

Simplfies to $A+D=22$ and $A-D=16$

Which rather simply goes to $A=19, D=3$

As we are looking for a 4-digit code 1903 works using 19 and 03 as the numbers. This has extra appeal as (recent) year numbers are popular 4-digit passwords.

> Alternatively we are given A..D. So I propose A19D as the code as A..D has room for two more digits.
> I am not convinced on the code part but I think the arithmetic part is valid.

Comment: Could it be 1903?

Comment: Alternatively the .. Could mean that the code should be the numbers represented by B and C. However if the numbers A to D are spaced uniformly on the number line, B and C are not integers.

Comment: @GordonK I like 1903, I was pondering it but I didn't put it into my head as 1903, I thought of it as 19 03. Years starting with 19 are rather common pin codes so that lines up nicely. I do like that better than A19D... Might put that into the answer, I just wish you didnt have to add a seemingly arbitrary number, though I suppose omitting the 3 is just as odd... As 4-digit tends to refer to numbers, I will go with 1903, but A19D is perfectly valid hex so that is somewhat interesting.

Comment: The code is digits only. No Hex. Unfortunately 1903 isn't the right answer.

Comment: If A..D refers to the diagonal line in the diagram running from A to D then the answer could be 19 3 3

Comment: that doesn't follow the key though, there should be some sort of logic connect on that right. otherwise the key would have been 832.

Comment: @moonbutt74 The key has already been used by Going hamateur above to work out the values of A and D

Comment: @Gordon K, hi iwas talking about 1933, the key into the puzzle seems to be 13 which is the sum of the / diagonal. That being what it is would it hold true that the sum of the \ diagonal would be the missing digits. So again If Going hamateur is spot on about the value of A D then 19+3+3=25

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer:

> 7133 ?

Based on the hint that:

> A and D are both one digit numbers, and the code is A13D

I tried using a variation on the approach that Going Hamateur used...

> I set:
>  A+2-3-8+D = A-8+3+2-D 
>  A-9+D = A-3-D 
>  D = 3 
>  When I substituted 3 for D, I found A-6=A-6

I then applied Moonbutt74's observation that:

> The Diagonal 2+3+8 = 13.I then solved A+3+D=13 
>  D=3, so A=7

Therefore, I believe the code is:

> 7133

Comment: I would be so happy just to see the correct answer because this really is making me nuts.

Comment: @Marwie Is this the code?

Answer (score 1):

`A` is number `11`, `D` is number `5`.

The first row `A+2 = 11+2 = 13`, what is written on the door.

The same is `8+D = 8+5 = 13`.

For columns `A-8 = 11-8 = 3`, the number in the centre of table.

The same is `D-2 = 5-2 =3`.

So you have to type `AD = 1105`

Comment: Okay upvote for the new angle, but it's the adding of the zero, that's still throwing me.

Comment: @moonbutt74 I think the 0 comes because there is "A..D". Points mean that there are 4 numbers, so `05` for D